# Как обновлять SSL сертификаты wildcard от Let's Encrypt?

Tags: centos, unix, ssl, centos7, letsencrypt

Дано: Сервер CentOS 7.
Установка, и начальное получение:

```
yum -y install yum-utils
yum-config-manager --enable rhui-REGION-rhel-server-extras rhui-REGION-rhel-server-optional
sudo yum install certbot
```

Дополнение для работы через CloudFlare DNS

```
sudo apt install python-pip
sudo pip install certbot-dns-cloudflare
```

Получение Wildcard SSL сертификата

```
certbot certonly --agree-tos -m info@exemple.com \
    --server https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory \
    --rsa-key-size 4096 \
    --dns-cloudflare --dns-cloudflare-credentials ~/.ssh/cloudflare.ini \
    --dns-cloudflare-propagation-seconds 90 \
    -d *.exemple.com -d exemple.com
```

Проблем нет, получаю `*.exemple.com` и `exemple.com` сертификаты.
Проблемы начинаются при обновление.
Авто-обновление:

```
0 0,12 * * * python -c 'import random; import time; time.sleep(random.random() * 3600)' && certbot renew --quiet --post-hook "systemctl reload nginx" --agree-tos --allow-subset-of-names
```

Проверка после обновлений:

```
certbot certificates
```

Обновляется только `exemple.com` без `*.exemple.com`. (при ручном обновление, кстати такая же ситуация)

*при получение `-d *.exemple.com -d exemple.com`*
*или же в кавычах `-d "*.exemple.com" -d exemple.com` нечего не меняет*

**Подскажите как быть, куда копать?**

UPD: (добавляю лог из `/var/log/letsencrypt/`)

```html
2018-12-13 12:24:03,451:DEBUG:certbot.main:certbot version: 0.27.1
2018-12-13 12:24:03,451:DEBUG:certbot.main:Arguments: ['--post-hook', 'systemctl reload nginx', '--agree-tos', '-q', '--allow-subset-of-names']
2018-12-13 12:24:03,451:DEBUG:certbot.main:Discovered plugins: PluginsRegistry(PluginEntryPoint#dns-cloudflare,PluginEntryPoint#manual,PluginEntryPoint#null,PluginEntryPoint#standalone,PluginEntryPoint#webroot)
2018-12-13 12:24:03,466:DEBUG:certbot.log:Root logging level set at 30
2018-12-13 12:24:03,467:INFO:certbot.log:Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
2018-12-13 12:24:03,492:DEBUG:certbot.plugins.selection:Requested authenticator <certbot.cli._Default object at 0x7f615c43c290> and installer <certbot.cli._Default object at 0x7f615c43c290>
2018-12-13 12:24:03,492:DEBUG:certbot.cli:Var allow_subset_of_names=True (set by user).
2018-12-13 12:24:03,492:DEBUG:certbot.cli:Var rsa_key_size=4096 (set by user).
2018-12-13 12:24:03,492:DEBUG:certbot.cli:Var server=https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory (set by user).
2018-12-13 12:24:03,493:DEBUG:certbot.cli:Var server=https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory (set by user).
2018-12-13 12:24:03,493:DEBUG:certbot.cli:Var account=set(['server']) (set by user).
2018-12-13 12:24:03,493:DEBUG:certbot.cli:Var post_hook=systemctl reload nginx (set by user).
2018-12-13 12:24:03,493:DEBUG:certbot.cli:Var dns_cloudflare_credentials=/etc/letsencrypt/dnscloudflare.ini (set by user).
2018-12-13 12:24:03,517:DEBUG:certbot.storage:Should renew, less than 30 days before certificate expiry 2019-01-12 04:54:13 UTC.
2018-12-13 12:24:03,517:INFO:certbot.renewal:Cert is due for renewal, auto-renewing...
2018-12-13 12:24:03,517:DEBUG:certbot.plugins.selection:Requested authenticator dns-cloudflare and installer None
2018-12-13 12:24:03,522:DEBUG:certbot.plugins.selection:Single candidate plugin: * dns-cloudflare
Description: Obtain certificates using a DNS TXT record (if you are using Cloudflare for DNS).
Interfaces: IAuthenticator, IPlugin
Entry point: dns-cloudflare = certbot_dns_cloudflare.dns_cloudflare:Authenticator
Initialized: <certbot_dns_cloudflare.dns_cloudflare.Authenticator object at 0x7f615c479a50>
Prep: True
2018-12-13 12:24:03,522:DEBUG:certbot.plugins.selection:Selected authenticator <certbot_dns_cloudflare.dns_cloudflare.Authenticator object at 0x7f615c479a50> and installer None
2018-12-13 12:24:03,522:INFO:certbot.plugins.selection:Plugins selected: Authenticator dns-cloudflare, Installer None
2018-12-13 12:24:03,526:DEBUG:certbot.main:Picked account: <Account(RegistrationResource(body=Registration(status=u'valid', terms_of_service_agreed=None, agreement=None, only_return_existing=None, contact=(u'mailto:fudeglan@gmail.com',), key=JWKRSA(key=<ComparableRSAKey(<cryptography.hazmat.backends.openssl.rsa._RSAPublicKey object at 0x7f615c4367d0>)>)), uri=u'https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/acct/34822954', new_authzr_uri=None, terms_of_service=u'https://letsencrypt.org/documents/LE-SA-v1.2-November-15-2017.pdf'), 4254012daa27a0d3d31fc569bad33afa, Meta(creation_host=u'hosted-by.ihc.ru', creation_dt=datetime.datetime(2018, 5, 12, 7, 7, 42, tzinfo=<UTC>)))>
2018-12-13 12:24:03,526:DEBUG:acme.client:Sending GET request to https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory.
2018-12-13 12:24:03,527:DEBUG:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org
2018-12-13 12:24:03,714:DEBUG:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org:443 "GET /directory HTTP/1.1" 200 658
2018-12-13 12:24:03,715:DEBUG:acme.client:Received response:
HTTP 200
Server: nginx
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 658
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=604800
Expires: Thu, 13 Dec 2018 09:24:03 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, no-store
Pragma: no-cache
Date: Thu, 13 Dec 2018 09:24:03 GMT
Connection: keep-alive

{
  "JCfCpssrZuk": "https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/adding-random-entries-to-the-directory/33417",
  "keyChange": "https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/key-change",
  "meta": {
    "caaIdentities": [
      "letsencrypt.org"
    ],
    "termsOfService": "https://letsencrypt.org/documents/LE-SA-v1.2-November-15-2017.pdf",
    "website": "https://letsencrypt.org"
  },
  "newAccount": "https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/new-acct",
  "newNonce": "https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/new-nonce",
  "newOrder": "https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/new-order",
  "revokeCert": "https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/revoke-cert"
}
2018-12-13 12:24:03,716:INFO:certbot.main:Renewing an existing certificate
2018-12-13 12:24:04,675:DEBUG:certbot.crypto_util:Generating key (4096 bits): /etc/letsencrypt/keys/0221_key-certbot.pem
2018-12-13 12:24:04,685:DEBUG:certbot.crypto_util:Creating CSR: /etc/letsencrypt/csr/0221_csr-certbot.pem
2018-12-13 12:24:04,686:DEBUG:acme.client:Requesting fresh nonce
2018-12-13 12:24:04,686:DEBUG:acme.client:Sending HEAD request to https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/new-order.
2018-12-13 12:24:04,853:DEBUG:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org:443 "HEAD /acme/new-order HTTP/1.1" 405 0
2018-12-13 12:24:04,854:DEBUG:acme.client:Received response:
HTTP 405
Server: nginx
Content-Type: application/problem+json
Content-Length: 103
Allow: POST
Replay-Nonce: egbR04nLfag6mw4TquK6jCDl6SHiHEtxizu7s4uTv8Y
Expires: Thu, 13 Dec 2018 09:24:04 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, no-store
Pragma: no-cache
Date: Thu, 13 Dec 2018 09:24:04 GMT
Connection: keep-alive


2018-12-13 12:24:04,854:DEBUG:acme.client:Storing nonce: egbR04nLfag6mw4TquK6jCDl6SHiHEtxizu7s4uTv8Y
2018-12-13 12:24:04,854:DEBUG:acme.client:JWS payload:
{
  "status": "pending", 
  "identifiers": [
    {
      "type": "dns", 
      "value": "*.workpan.ru"
    }, 
    {
      "type": "dns", 
      "value": "workpan.ru"
    }
  ], 
  "resource": "new-order"
}
2018-12-13 12:24:04,868:DEBUG:acme.client:Sending POST request to https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/new-order:
{
  "protected": "eyJub25jZSI6ICJlZ2JSMDRuTGZhZzZtdzRUcXVLNmpDRGw2U0hpSEV0eGl6dTdzNHVUdjhZIiwgInVybCI6ICJodHRwczovL2FjbWUtdjAyLmFwaS5sZXRzZW5jcnlwdC5vcmcvYWNtZS9uZXctb3JkZXIiLCAia2lkIjogImh0dHBzOi8vYWNtZS12MDIuYXBpLmxldHNlbmNyeXB0Lm9yZy9hY21lL2FjY3QvMzQ4MjI5NTQiLCAiYWxnIjogIlJTMjU2In0", 
  "payload": "ewogICJzdGF0dXMiOiAicGVuZGluZyIsIAogICJpZGVudGlmaWVycyI6IFsKICAgIHsKICAgICAgInR5cGUiOiAiZG5zIiwgCiAgICAgICJ2YWx1ZSI6ICIqLndvcmtwYW4ucnUiCiAgICB9LCAKICAgIHsKICAgICAgInR5cGUiOiAiZG5zIiwgCiAgICAgICJ2YWx1ZSI6ICJ3b3JrcGFuLnJ1IgogICAgfQogIF0sIAogICJyZXNvdXJjZSI6ICJuZXctb3JkZXIiCn0", 
  "signature": "chnr8WfyjeLmrQfG3cRoQ9rII3pwPsVjh4sF9k8K4Kc_AxKRai6XDHaJmdCeSAHGyqWASVvDS3bf9Q-ksavTOyDhX_UNIUH5hI9MWEITcCwtPG7aFa_gOTxpQhPbRljlIk0aLaAyWjZ9njgOzV38sDs5aNQx2WR5PwYVe3pAWNcbCE2ckmXhEyc_tPKPyUycARXMGJp0raagw33O6RooIdl69qCcutHofhFAzEzen_kQ4ECIRkJ-fPn_SiKLAdO5_QLiQHBgvDnqdOD5USbNiY64Dcv_SAdX3CVLf8qXRhWTrCCIDXbXneA13Swn5am0xCLI5_iIf-nTjQNgcagW1PmO1tXA0ZrQwfzNe5xjfs_FQQJYOVzJ999B9FenEJxjT7ZmzjS5AgRqoq71_GcCsxjgzVeZ1feVjv-9DppUjcIkHq2Pf1XuCUTKBhgULNqaubOLDpKHgS7Y9M2bQg50vHdCMKRFYcwZuzKYKmCLBS5EogL8oiNLiv2fNcshm8LkUHv-gJfNhNymN-3iX7GpL7jfCEVJfM6xWTK54DmQVnGZX4NyeMdLxnixydJaNsog5ABleH3EDDssZYO7uzsMywUtHMgUf_TzxEGcDwkrSzV7dt8DlToQ0DNMC_AXIW5hQQupeMEuqZSN7gqoDes50-3VfBrwXk8doT91wXgoeSk"
}
2018-12-13 12:24:05,087:DEBUG:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org:443 "POST /acme/new-order HTTP/1.1" 201 532
2018-12-13 12:24:05,088:DEBUG:acme.client:Received response:
HTTP 201
Server: nginx
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 532
Boulder-Requester: 34822954
Location: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/order/34822954/218814899
Replay-Nonce: eHVu--hESPJyx-IHjGaFUxZlJd9iA8MzAxFqsCiFBiw
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=604800
Expires: Thu, 13 Dec 2018 09:24:05 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, no-store
Pragma: no-cache
Date: Thu, 13 Dec 2018 09:24:05 GMT
Connection: keep-alive

{
  "status": "pending",
  "expires": "2018-12-20T09:24:04.979831627Z",
  "identifiers": [
    {
      "type": "dns",
      "value": "*.workpan.ru"
    },
    {
      "type": "dns",
      "value": "workpan.ru"
    }
  ],
  "authorizations": [
    "https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/authz/wfOE9CAcbgWc_mj-0gC3Rxl2oGpQHy7FqpYROFOHPFk",
    "https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/authz/HkbHW48lfwP6hY79ZYdmUhlAA-Y-SmGL7C8n4n2076A"
  ],
  "finalize": "https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/finalize/34822954/218814899"
}
2018-12-13 12:24:05,088:DEBUG:acme.client:Storing nonce: eHVu--hESPJyx-IHjGaFUxZlJd9iA8MzAxFqsCiFBiw
2018-12-13 12:24:05,089:DEBUG:acme.client:Sending GET request to https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/authz/wfOE9CAcbgWc_mj-0gC3Rxl2oGpQHy7FqpYROFOHPFk.
2018-12-13 12:24:05,266:DEBUG:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org:443 "GET /acme/authz/wfOE9CAcbgWc_mj-0gC3Rxl2oGpQHy7FqpYROFOHPFk HTTP/1.1" 200 421
2018-12-13 12:24:05,267:DEBUG:acme.client:Received response:
HTTP 200
Server: nginx
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 421
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=604800
Expires: Thu, 13 Dec 2018 09:24:05 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, no-store
Pragma: no-cache
Date: Thu, 13 Dec 2018 09:24:05 GMT
Connection: keep-alive

{
  "identifier": {
    "type": "dns",
    "value": "workpan.ru"
  },
  "status": "pending",
  "expires": "2018-12-20T09:24:04Z",
  "challenges": [
    {
      "type": "dns-01",
      "status": "pending",
      "url": "https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/challenge/wfOE9CAcbgWc_mj-0gC3Rxl2oGpQHy7FqpYROFOHPFk/10281742024",
      "token": "phFsXrhW_vTsC3_foQuO6L575huEbzbEEOxfNw4FBxY"
    }
  ],
  "wildcard": true
}
2018-12-13 12:24:05,268:DEBUG:acme.client:Sending GET request to https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/authz/HkbHW48lfwP6hY79ZYdmUhlAA-Y-SmGL7C8n4n2076A.
2018-12-13 12:24:05,460:DEBUG:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org:443 "GET /acme/authz/HkbHW48lfwP6hY79ZYdmUhlAA-Y-SmGL7C8n4n2076A HTTP/1.1" 200 1158
2018-12-13 12:24:05,461:DEBUG:acme.client:Received response:
HTTP 200
Server: nginx
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 1158
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=604800
Expires: Thu, 13 Dec 2018 09:24:05 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, no-store
Pragma: no-cache
Date: Thu, 13 Dec 2018 09:24:05 GMT
Connection: keep-alive

{
  "identifier": {
    "type": "dns",
    "value": "workpan.ru"
  },
  "status": "pending",
  "expires": "2018-12-20T09:24:04Z",
  "challenges": [
    {
      "type": "http-01",
      "status": "pending",
      "url": "https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/challenge/HkbHW48lfwP6hY79ZYdmUhlAA-Y-SmGL7C8n4n2076A/10281742032",
      "token": "GtENDWWqb7Io2XwH8KI4_x2u9huYy9WVfqtweLTfFUw"
    },
    {
      "type": "tls-alpn-01",
      "status": "pending",
      "url": "https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/challenge/HkbHW48lfwP6hY79ZYdmUhlAA-Y-SmGL7C8n4n2076A/10281742033",
      "token": "k0Ci3Tg7Q2y-A1YpFAUVHEWBQaaaMAGHoHyNh1ZVNx0"
    },
    {
      "type": "dns-01",
      "status": "pending",
      "url": "https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/challenge/HkbHW48lfwP6hY79ZYdmUhlAA-Y-SmGL7C8n4n2076A/10281742035",
      "token": "3sNBDo2K37LKt9_NVEsG8teC6Sql6nYMhOsMsYjtz0U"
    },
    {
      "type": "tls-sni-01",
      "status": "pending",
      "url": "https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/challenge/HkbHW48lfwP6hY79ZYdmUhlAA-Y-SmGL7C8n4n2076A/10281742036",
      "token": "6uuN599-P9Rhh2LlxLT7FIO3vZ2gJPGHACDBZ3UMJx4"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: `~/.ssh/cloudflare.ini` — наверно, лучше **явно** указать путь к файлу, а не использовать user-специфичное значение. p.s. ну, и, наверняка certbot что-то в лог пишет (или в stdout/stderr, ввиду чего лучше сначала вручную запустить обновление).

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin 1. посмотрите пожалуйста добавил лог. 2. `--dns-cloudflare-credentials ~/.ssh/cloudflare.ini` это старая команда, я путь к `cloudflare.ini` где-то в настройках прописал, так что он от туда их берет. 3. Проблема с получением или же обновлением нет. Проблема именно в обновление *wildcard* да, и я не могу понять почему

Comment: на всякий, пути же прописываешь нормальными полными, а не с тильдой (`~`)?

Comment: кстати лог какой-то больно старый... это точно тот?

Comment: @Fat-Zer с путями всё норм, он же получает сертификат и обнояляет его, все норм. Старый (сейчас до обновы 40 дней где-то есть). Там в логах есть момент, где он пытается получить wildcard сертификат, логи двух доменов а потом бац. И уже проверка только одного домена, вот этот, самый момент

Comment: @FarkhodDaniyarov, там в ответе `"wildcard": true` может они, теперь один сертификат выдают и на основной и на поддомены? содержимое его не смотрел?

Comment: @Fat-Zer так верно, один сертификат, но должен быть и на основной домен и на все его под-домены, когда я делаю получить через `certbot certonly --agree-tos ` то я его получаю, радуюсь 90 дней и при обновление, слетает, получаю только для `example.com`, все на под-доменах падает, все ругается, приходится в ручном режиме обратно получать, и так каждый раз, без автомата

Comment: @FarkhodDaniyarov, ладно... у меня, если честно, идеи кончились...

Comment: @Fat-Zer спасибо, буду искать решение